Can I build a project targeting .NET 8 using msbuild from older version of Visual Studio?
I have an older version of Visual Studio 2022 that came out with .NET 7. Due to system requirements reasons I cannot upgrade the Visual Studio 2022 to the most recent version that supports .NET 8.
I thus installed only the .NET 8 SDK and was hoping to use the 'msbuild' that comes with the older version of Visual Studio 2022 (.NET 7 - 17.6.5) to build my project targeting .NET 8.
Unfortunately when I run the msbuild command:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Temp\BlazorApp1\BlazorApp1.sln" /property:Configuration=Debug

I get the following error:
error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0. Either target .NET 7.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 8.0

However, when I list my SDK using dotnet --list-sdks I get:
2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
7.0.306 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
8.0.302 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

Why does msbuild not see the installed sdk for .NET 8? Is it because it's the msbuild that comes with Visual Studio 2022 for .NET 7? I know I could get the project to build using dotnet and adding a global.json file but unfortunately I can't use the dotnet command, and must get msbuild to build the project.

The standalone MSBuild executable is installed as part of Visual Studio. The dotnet tool has its own embedded copy of MSBuild. dotnet build uses the embedded version and dotnet msbuild is a pass-thru to the embedded MSBuild. If you have a working msbuild command line, e.g. msbuild <something>, you can change to dotnet msbuild <something>.

Open your Project Solution File and try to Update VisualStudioVersion to latest version
Try to update MsBuild version as per your SDK version, to know your SDK version look for global.json file
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/8.0/version-requirements
enter image description here
